# What is the MySQL Equivalent of SQL CE?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, sql-server-ce

I'd like to know if WordPress can be pointed at the DB equivalent of SQL CE.  I presume the answer is yes, if MySQL has something equivalent to SQL CE.

What's the low down on this?

**Update**: Given the answers so far, I will re-state my question so that it is more easily understood: "Can WordPress be pointed at SQLite instead of MySQL?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there is no MySQL equivalent of SQL Compact Edition. You may want to check SQLite instead (www.sqlite.org). Wordpress supports this.

Comment: I see now that WordPress does not officially support SQLite, but there is a plugin that enables the capability.

Comment: @Rich, +1 if you didn't summarize my answer 6 minutes after I posted. Furthermore, *WordPress supports this* is misleading. I don't believe in down voting, but this is a poor answer. *Don't try this at home kids*.

Comment: @Brent Arias, as noted by my answer, it's highly unlikely this plugin provides comprehensive support. The very fact that it is a plugin means it could not as thousands of lines of core code load before a plugin - which is enabled via a record in the wp_options table. *Chicken before the egg.*

Comment: @JasonMcCreary I was replying to the post from my mobile and honestly didn't see your answer until after. Should have said it was a plugin. _Still learning_

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to know if WordPress can be pointed at the DB equivalent of SQL CE

**No.**

Or at least *not easily*. WordPress is built on top the LAMP stack where *M* is strictly MySQL. Although it has a database abstraction layer (WPDB), the code and plugins are littered and accept direct SQL code (MySQL).

If you are interested in this, check out the discussion in the [WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Alternative_Databases#Solutions/).

> What is the MySQL Equivalent of SQL CE?

In my opinion, I'd make the jump and say SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this surprising but MySQL can be stripped down to operate like a Compact Edition database. MySQL (eh Oracle) does not seem to support the Embedded MySQL anymore ([**or at least they make hard to find**](http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/white-papers/mysql_wp_embedded_win_guide.php)). However, you can make the following tweeks to MySQL:

### **TWEEK #1 : Disable InnoDB**

Start mysqld with this in my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
skip-innodb
```

Benefits

- Faster startup of mysql
- Does not create ibdata1, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1
- Does not allocate default InnoDB Buffer Pool (MySQL 5.5 128M, before MySQL 5.5 8MB)
- Less memory consumption (InnoDB code is not memory resident)

### **TWEEK #2 : Preload Indexes of the Most Important MyISAM Tables**

By default, MyISAM uses the Key Cache and its size is governed by key_buffer_Size. Interestingly, MyISAM allows you to create a dedicate key cache for onr ot more tables.

For example, if you have the table mysite.wp_posts, you can create a dedicated 256M key cache as follows:

```
SET GLOBAL wp_posts_cache.key_buffer_size = 1024 * 1024 * 256;
CACHE INDEX mysite.wp_posts IN wp_posts_cache;
LOAD INDEX INTO CACHE mysite.wp_posts;
```

You can have this done at start by doing this:

```
echo "SET GLOBAL wp_posts_cache.key_buffer_size = 1024 * 1024 * 256;" > /var/lib/mysql/startup.sql
echo "CACHE INDEX mysite.wp_posts IN wp_posts_cache;" > /var/lib/mysql/startup.sql
echo "LOAD INDEX INTO CACHE mysite.wp_posts;" > /var/lib/mysql/startup.sql
```

Give it a Try !!!
then add this to my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
init-file=/var/lib/mysql/startup.sql
```

Then, restart mysql